# Juntar duas <h:dataTable> com jQuery sem perder os registros após o update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-3.5

Tenho duas datatables, a primeira carrega 5 registros ao carregar a página e a segunda fica oculta e vazia.

Sempre que o scroll chegar até o final da página eu vou no banco de dados, carrego mais 5 registros e preencho no arraylist da segunda datatable e depois com jQuery eu dou um append desses registros da segunda tabela para a primeira tabela:

```
x = $(#segundaTabela);
$(x).children().children().each(function(){
    $(this).clone().appendTo($('.primeiraTabela').children());
    });
```

Tudo funciona normal, porém eu reparei que as requisições ajax dos registros da segunda tabela param de funcionar quando eu do mais um update nela.

Tem como resolver isso?

Estou fazendo isso apenas para deixar o carregamento dos dados mais dinâmico sem fica esse refresh na tabela 1, ou seja, carrego sempre na segunda tabela oculta e depois com jQuery clono os registros na primeira, mas se eu atualizar a segunda, mesmo os registros que foram clonados param de funcionar as requisições ajax.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt @Marcus Vinicius. Ao invés de criar uma nova pergunta é melhor editar a pergunta. Digo isso pois tem outra pergunta sua aqui no site com o mesmo título. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100604/juntar-duas-hdatatable-com-jquery-sem-perder-os-registros-ap%C3%B3s-o-update-nas-t

Comment: Marcus, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Eu entendi o que você está fazendo e o que você quer, mas você não postou nenhum código relevante (como o código da tabela ou o que carrega os registros quando a página rola), de forma que fica difícil adivinhar o que possa estar acontecendo. Tem algum erro no console JavaScript do browser?

Comment: De qualquer forma, me parece que usar os componentes JSF dessa forma é um risco em potencial. Componentes JSF normalmente são stateful, isto é, dependem de estado no servidor associado a eles. Nesse caso, adicionar as linhas em uma tabela no lado do cliente vai fazer com que qualquer ação associada a essas linhas deixe de funcionar. Isso sem falar em que você está interferindo na lógica dos componentes do Prime Faces. O comportamento de um componente que tem a estrutura alterada externamente é imprevisível e pode ser a causa do Ajax parar de funcionar. Sugestão: use uma tabela normal.